# Is this sentence gramatically correct? Use of would have and had

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, perfect-aspect

Is this sentence correctly written?

> I would never have had the chance to become who i am if would not worked as hard as i did.

Also, I'm a native Spanish speaker and i can't find the differences between the structures "Would have" and "Had" in some contexts.  I know is wrong to translate directly from one language to the another and that's what is probably confusing me. Could you tell me the main difference between each of those words?

Comment: The pronoun "I" should always be capitalized.

Comment: Carlos, just think how you might translate into English something that had in Spanish started off more along the lines of one of: *Jamás hubiera tenido la oportunidad de convertirme en el profesional consumado que soy hoy en día {si no hubiese / de no haber / sin haber} trabajado tanto durante muchos años.*

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are definitely missing an 'I', as Licky Cat says.

Secondly, you need to say 'if I *had* not worked...' (or more naturally, 'if I hadn't worked...').

Thirdly, some people might say 'if I wouldn't have worked...', but only, I think, in American English. It's probably better to avoid this.

Oh, and fourthly, 'I' is always capitalised in English.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't correct. There's an 'I' before the 'worked hard'. I think, in Spanish, you say ‘Estoy’ or ‘Soy’ in front of a sentence, and that covers 'I am', but in English, you have to say 'I' in front of the sentence for the first person singular.

Try visiting the English for learners community, I think you'll get a lot more from them.

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer. i will give a try to that community you're suggesting . Beyond the lack of the pronoun in the sentence, is there other grammatical mistake?

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice at first. The 'would not' there has to be replaced with 'had not', as you said was difficult for you to understand. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything to support it when I searched it up, and I find it a bit difficult to explain it accurately. As I said, the English from other languages forum could probably give you much better results than I can.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not correctly written.

The grammatically correct and idiomatic way of saying it would be:

*I would never have had the chance to become who I am,  if I had not worked as hard as I did.*

An alternative idiomatic ending would be *...had I not worked as hard as I did*.

At least that is my British view.